# C globally shared variable vs extern variable

Tags: c, variables, static, global

This is a theoretical question:
Assume I have 2 source files / compilation units, A.c and B.c

A.c:

```
int x;
```

B.c:

```
int x;
```

The variable x is considered to be shared between the objects. That is, one int was allocated
somewhere and this variable is global and visible to all source files that declare it.

However I can also do this:
B.c:

```
extern int x;
```

Is there any difference between extern and plain global variables in this context?
And what is the difference in general?

Thanks!!

Comment: See [What are extern variables in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/1433387#1433387) for a lot of information.  Your A.c and B.c code (with `int x;` twice) only works as a common extension (recognized in Annex J of the C standard).  The variant with `extern int x;` matches the standard's requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one definitions of `x` in `A.c` and one definition of `x` in `B.c` your program invokes undefined behavior.

Some toolchains will accept your program by defining the undefined behavior in some particular cases but you cannot rely on this for all compilers.

> C99, 6.9p5) "If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a sizeof operator whose result is an integer constant),        somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one"

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that it won't link without `extern`, you'll get a multiple definition error. Only the version with `extern` works.